# Create a node using the REST API

Tags: 8

I am trying to create a node from a different server via REST API, utilizing the Drupal 8 REST API and the Poster plugin for the browser. 
I posted the request as shown below, and I got the following output.

```
{
    "message": ""
}
```

[image]

I already enabled the service end_point to create, retrieve, update, and delete the content in the REST API configuration.

[image]

[image]

What is happening? Is it the right way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know the D8 https://www.drupal.org/project/services but they state

"Services 4.x is currently in development. Since Drupal 8 contains REST functionality in CORE, Services in Drupal 8 will be slightly different. Were aiming to accomplish the following for D8."

Guess you should checkout https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/3-post-for-creating-content-entities

Comment: Technically you don't need the Services module in Drupal 8 to create nodes via REST. This page will also be helpful: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein . Actually am trying to create a node from another server . Thats is the scenario .

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I am going to Explain you in a very simple way using a Postman Software. 
 1. Enable the restui Module. 
 2. Add the basic_auth authentication.
 3. Get the X-CSRF-Token from /rest/session/token.
 4. Follow things by this image:

[image]

 5. Add the following text into your Body.

[image]

And hit the Send Button Its **Done!**

Answer (score 2):

Drupal officially support 2 
Authentication providers

1. Cookie
2. Basic_auth

( Note ) Personally, I recommend ‘Cookie’,
 
 because it is useful for mobile and third-party developers.

=================  Login ==================
How can Login Drupal’s APIs in PostMan ?
Method: Post
URL : http://localhost/drupal_8_bs4_theme_01/user/login
Parameters: Key=value  --->  ?_format=json
Headers :   Content-Type = application/json
Body :  Raw → application/Json
`{
"name": "test",
"pass": "test"
}`

Response :
`{
    "current_user": {
        "uid": "25",
        "name": "test"
    },
    "csrf_token": "-Cgh_1vMeVvFn3E5KePfXKWPeVg2Rhf6kURcnVEQbwA",
    "logout_token": "PxfO3uR4gUWFn5hWXgvKBr-4gsB8HMOdT4v5okrZxC8"
}`

======== Create Node Using Cookie Auth  ======
After Login How can You Create Node ?
Method:  Post
URL : http://localhost/drupal_8_bs4_theme_01/entity/node?_format=json
Headers :   
Content-Type = application/json
X-CSRF-Token =  8km8Kh5enGfT1_fpYGg6q6g3BWUhjMa3L3EijUphJu8
Body:
`{
  "type":[{"target_id":"page"}],
  "title":[{"value":"Hello World 221"}],
  "body":[{"value":"How are you?"}]
}`

======== Create Node Using Basic Auth  ======
Method: Post
URL :-  http://localhost/drupal_8_bs4_theme_01/entity/node
Query Params : 
 Key = _format
Value = hal_json
Authorization:
Basic Auth: u -> admin and password -> admin
Headers:
X-CSRF-Token    =    Token Which you get like    CVieBUrFLSjUsXLGLJ-xW6krdKdAcOkpJK0WP6rzK_0
Content-Type       =    application/hal+json
Accept                  =    application/hal+json

Body:
`{
  "type":[{"target_id":"page"}],
  "title":[{"value":"Hello World 221"}],
  "body":[{"value":"How are you?"}]
}`

====================  LogOut =======================
How can Logout Drupal’s APIs in PostMan ?
Method: Post
URL: http://localhost/drupal_8_bs4_theme_01/user/logout
Parameters: Key=value  --->  ?X-CSRF-Token=-Cgh_1vMeVvFn3E5KePfXKWPeVg2Rhf6kURcnVEQbwA

(Note) I Think Body is Optional

Body :  Raw → application/Json 
`{ "csrf_token": "hU2BZsfvXjcT92rWvxQyiZ1wOD-bMtOkG2Mlj2pSPuw",   "logout_token": "UUiitmj854Qm_UpuVZq-PK_0FOXQA9wMIqhVLbXBbFM" }`

Response :
Redirect to URL

For Details Visit Following Links 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/jsonapi/get-post-patch-and-delete
https://www.drupal.org/node/2806623
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/rest/javascript-and-drupal-8-restful-web-services

Answer (score 0):

My plan was first make it work using the **`postman client`** and port the same using **`curl`** request . So first i made a curl request from command line as

```
curl --include --request POST --user username:password --header 'Content-type: application/hal+json' http://192.168.1.243/node --data-binary '{"_links":
{"type":{"href":"http://192.168.1.243/rest/type/node/article"}}, "title":[{"value":"My first page"}],"body":[{"value":"How are you?"}]}'
```

And that was worked (created the node in **`192.168.1.243`**) . Then i made the **`curl`** request from php as follows :

```
$data = '{"_links":
{"type":{"href":"http://192.168.1.243/rest/type/node/article"}}, "title":[{"value":"My first page"}],"body":[{"value":"How are you?"}]}';

        $url = "http://192.168.1.243/node";
        $curl_connection = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt");
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/hal+json'));
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
        curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
```

And that was all . The **`node created`** in the remote server .

In postman client cant set the **`HEADER`** as **`'Content-type: application/hal+json'`** .  I think that may caused the issue . Any insights welcome .