# RESTful web services custom reponse when creating nodes?

Tags: 8

I have enabled RESTful Web Services and REST UI.

I have followed the guide in this answer and am able to create nodes using the REST api.
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/256429/105808

However, when I send the Post request, the body returned has so much data, its almost difficult to read through and a much is not needed. For example, the response, contains, revision ID, Language, if its promoted to front page, if its published, stick, about 3 different paths, which all of this I dont need. I only need the ID, Title, and a few fields which I added. Is there anyway to remove all the rest?

I have created a REST Export view which contains the data, is it possible to use this REST view? I have also tried removing the fields from the node but they still show in the REST response even though they dont show at all on the node.

Anyway I can just disable all this unnecessary reponse data?

Thanks