# Creating content on via REST API using POST: proper formatting of json?

Tags: services, 9

I'm trying to do a POST to create content on my site, but I get an *Access Denied for creating field: changed* even though I am an administrator role. When I remove the "changed" field in the JSON I get the *Website encountered an unexpected error* error. I assume my JSON format is incorrect. I got it from doing a GET on one of the published nodes, and just removed the nid and uuid values in the JSON.

Or is there a better way to get the proper format I need to create content or am I including too many fields in the JSON?

```
curl -u xxxxxx:yyyyyy -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
    "vid": [{"value": 349}],
    "langcode": [{"value": "en"}],
    "type": [{"target_id": "chats", "target_type": "node_type", "target_uuid": "1332c2f2-ecce-49fd-bff4-4bf37dd24f7b"}],
    "status": [{"value": true}],
    "uid": [{"target_id": 1, "target_type": "user", "target_uuid": "0e0c2c1d-ed85-4152-bbd6-3821005b07fd", "url": "\/user\/1"}],
    "title": [{"value": "tessssst"}],
    "created": [{"value": "2023-03-15T17:36:47+00:00", "format": "Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP"}],
    "changed": [{"value": "2023-05-09T19:40:40+00:00", "format": "Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP"}],
    "promote": [{"value": false}],
    "sticky": [{"value": false}],
    "default_langcode": [{"value": true}],
    "revision_translation_affected": [{"value": true}],
    "path": [{"alias": null, "pid": null, "langcode": "en"}],
    "publish_on": [],
    "unpublish_on": [],
    "body": [{"value": "<p>this is a test!<\/p>", "format": "full_html", "processed": "<p>this is a test!<\/p>", "summary": ""}],
    "field_chat_parent": [],
    "field_page": [{"value": 2}]
  }' \
  https://xxxx.yyy/node?_format=json
```

[image]

Comment: Are you passing a cookie or authenticated token?

Comment: using basic authentication. created a user for it.

Comment: Yes but are you passing that _back_ with each request? This is required with curl. I do not see that in your request.

Comment: its in the first line "-u " --- i have it blanked out in red.

Comment: I'm testing on just the "basic page" and i still get this error: **{"message":"Access denied on creating field \u0027changed\u0027."}** -- if i remove the "changed" field from POST, it shows a website has encountered an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging around a few hours. This answer helped: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/283883/12585 -- Many of the answers as of 2023-May on the internet is for Drupal 8 and some of the parameters are deprecated like hal+json. This works for **Drupal 9.4** as of today.

I managed to first create a node using the most simplified amount of variables:

```
curl -u myuser:password -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
  "type":[{"target_id":"page"}],
  "title":[{"value":"Hello World xxxx221"}],
  "body":[{"value":"<p>this is a test!<\/p>", "format": "full_html"}]
}' \
  https://xxxxxxxxx.com/node?_format=json
```

Pasting the above into the command line will just work and won't throw an error. The error I ran into was due to the fact I was copying all the json output from the initial query and pasting everything to the POST. Some of the things will need to be changed to make it work with POST for **Drupal 9**.